# Count the number of times a value meets a criteria within a rolling window

Tags: python, pandas, rolling-computation

```
In [4]: data = pd.DataFrame([[9,4,16],[5,4,2],[1,3,13],[26,7,3]])               

In [5]: data                                                                    
Out[5]: 
    0  1   2
0   9  4  16
1   5  4   2
2   1  3  13
3  26  7   3
```

I want to count how many time the values in a rolling window of size n in column 0 are greater than the value in column 1. In this case the window including the values 9, 5, 1, 26 (size 4) would yield the number 3 since 9, 5, and  26 but not 1 are greater than 4. Similarly, if applied to column 2 using a rolling window of 4 on column 1, the value would be 0 since none of 4, 4, 3, 7 are greater than 16

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this.

However, I am not sure what output you want, because output will be as series as shown & you will have NaN's until the rolling window value is actually reached.

```
def func(arr):
    count = 0
    for i in arr : 
        if i > len(arr) : 
            count = count + 1
    return count
data[0].rolling(4).apply(lambda x: func(x),raw=False)
```

**Output**

```
0    NaN
1    NaN
2    NaN
3    3.0
```

```
data[0].rolling(2).apply(lambda x: func(x),raw=False)
```

will result in

```
0    NaN
1    2.0
2    1.0
3    1.0
```

Comment: Thanks. I realize that what I am looking for is a way to iterate through the values in Rolling so that I can compare them to the value in a particular row and count how many times they are greater than such value. Unfortunately, iteration over the values in Rolling is not implemented yet.